# MariaDB. Какой workbench выбрать?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Какой инструмент для работы с MariaDB выбрать? Каким пользуетесь вы? Речь идет о Raspberry Pi OS, производной Debian Linux.

Comment: А какая у вас задача и требования? А то это как спросить что мне надеть сегодня? Во что одеты вы? :-)

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Если вкратце, то задача раз в определенный отрезок времени писать значения температурных датчиков в БД, чтобы потом их анализировать. Как в текущем режиме, так и постфактум. А про одежду вы верно подметили, на вкус и цвет... :) А воркбенч - это, скорее, временное решение, чтобы их, данные, например, сортировать и т.д...

Comment: Попробуйте `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: @Феоктист Пупырышкин, phpMyAdmin прекрасное приложение, но только для этого случая нужно будет специально ставить web-сервер...

Comment: В таком случае Вам лучше всего ставить не на сам сервер, а стороннее приложение которым Вы будете подключаться к серверу с БД с другого компьютера. Это даст Вам огромное кол-во приложений в зависимости от ОС стоящей на этом компьютере. Из тех, что под Windows рекомендовал бы https://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/manager - но он платный с триальным периодом. Из тех что и бесплатны и под любую ОС - попробуйте https://dbeaver.io/

Comment: @Феоктист Пупырышкин Благодарю за информацию! Буду смотреть дальше!

Answer (score 1):

Вам подойдёт [консольный клиент](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-command-line-client/) mariadb. У него есть опция `-e`, которая позволяет выполнить запрос. Формируете запрос (скриптом на баше или как вам удобно) и передаёте его в mariadb.